# How to declare a variable before assign it in React using Typescript without "Index signature is missing in type" Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to declare a variable named 'reports' and assign it to an array of arrays with string and number types but the problem is when I assign it there are some errors.
the code is like this:

```js
... // I get the response from an api
let reports: [string, string | number];
      for (let key of response.data) {
        reports.push(Object.entries(key)); // key = {a: 'a', b: 3, c: 'c'} something like this
      }
```

the errors:

```
1. Variable 'reports' is used before being assigned.
2. Argument of type '[string, unknown][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.
  Type '[string, unknown][]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
3. Variable 'reports' is used before being assigned.
```

**Update**

I made these changes but still I've got a problem and don't know how to fix the error.

```js
interface Report {
  [report: string]: [string, string | number];
}
```

```js
let reports: Report[] = [];
      for (let key of response.data) {
        reports.push(Object.entries(key));
      }
```

**Error**

```
Argument of type '[string, string | number][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Report'.
  Index signature is missing in type '[string, string | number][]'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the variable e.g.

```
let reports: [string, string | number] = [];
```

and make `reports` an array

```
let reports: [string, string | number][] = [];
```

Comment: it solves two errors but not this one: 'Argument of type '[string, unknown][]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, string | number]'.
  Type '[string, unknown][]' is missing the following properties from type '[string, string | number]': 0, 1'

Comment: Shouldn't interfaces be used here to simplify the approach, also the data is JSON, I don't think the declaration `[string, string | number]` solves the problem

Comment: @MuhammadZia but it will turn to this type eventually: `[string, string | number]`. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: I would suggest implementing interfaces, but if you want a quick easy fix:
`let reports: JSON[];`

Comment: @MuhammadZia Thanks, I used interfaces instead of declaring the type in variable declaration. But I still have the second error: `Argument of type '[string, unknown][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.
  Type '[string, unknown][]' is not assignable to type 'string'.`. Any suggestion for fixing that?

Comment: The error is because it is an JSON object, if you stringify the JSON it becomes : `"key" : "value"` and type string cannot handle such data, did you try `let reports: JSON[]` ?

Comment: @MuhammadZia Yes I did and the error is: `Argument of type '[string, unknown][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JSON'.
  Type '[string, unknown][]' is missing the following properties from type 'JSON': parse, stringify, [Symbol.toStringTag]`